# How to change my model's parameters manually?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I have a model:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 3)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(3, 2)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(2, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x1 = self.fc1(x)
        x = torch.relu(x1)
        x2 = self.fc2(x)
        x = torch.relu(x2)
        x3 = self.fc3(x)
        return x3, x2, x1

net = Model()
```

I'm trying to manually update the parameters with

```
i, j = torch.meshgrid(torch.arange(3), torch.arange(2))
i = i.reshape(-1)
j = j.reshape(-1)
update = torch.ones(6,1)
print(i)
print(j)
print(update.squeeze())
print(net.fc2.weight[j,i].data)
net.fc2.weight[j,i].data += update.squeeze()
print(net.fc2.weight[j,i].data)

>>> tensor([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2])
    tensor([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
    tensor([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
    tensor([-0.0209, -0.3770,  0.4982, -0.2123, -0.2630, -0.5580])
    tensor([-0.0209, -0.3770,  0.4982, -0.2123, -0.2630, -0.5580])
```

But nothing seems to change.

However, if I do

```
print(net.fc2.weight[1].data)
net.fc2.weight[1].data += 1
print(net.fc2.weight[1].data)

>>> tensor([-0.3770, -0.2123, -0.5580])
    tensor([0.6230, 0.7877, 0.4420])
```

They do change.

What am I doing wrong in the first approach and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point you are missing is simple: when you do a "constant indexing", you get a "view" of the tensor, otherwise (i.e. indexing with another tensor) you get a new tensor or a new node in the computation graph.

`PyTorch` provides a `.data_ptr()` method to peek into the underlying memory pointer.

```
>> net.fc2.weight.data.data_ptr()
2911054070464

>> net.fc2.weight[1].data.data_ptr()
2911054070464
```

Constant indexing did not change the underlying raw data. However, indexing with a tensor creates a new node and hence a new underlying raw memory location

```
>> net.fc2.weight[j, i].data.data_ptr()
2911054068672
```

So, in your case, you are creating a new tensor/node with `net.fc2.weight[j,i]` and assigning new value to it. That's why your original tensor remains unchanged. In the constant indexing case, you are changing the same memory location, hence the change is reflected.

---

To fix your problem, instead of doing this

```
net.fc2.weight[j,i].data += update.squeeze()
```

do this

```
net.fc2.weight.data[j,i] += update.squeeze()
```

.. essentially grabbing the underlying `.data` first and then indexing it, which means the indexing operation is entirely out of autograd's tracking machinery.

Comment: Ha! That's ridiculous simple and there's no way I would have thought of that. Thanks a lot!